# Como fazer para que uma determinada função me retorne o valor de uma variável data e uma numérica em php?

Tags: php, funções, variáveis, return

Criei uma função que calcula o próximo dia útil de uma determinada data que ela recebe, porém além de me retornar esta nova data queria que ela incrementasse um número a mais a uma variável de contagem ($prdia) e me retornasse essa variável também. Como faço isso?

O código é o seguinte:

```
  if ($tipo_prz == 'DU'){
    $prdia = 1;    
  //a variável 'prz' foi obtida em outra parte do código   
  // a data_corrigida_DU também foi obtida em outra parte    
      while ($prdia < $prz){
        $data_corrigida_DU = proximoDiaUtilPr($data_corrigida_DU);
      }
    }
```

A função está assim:

```
function proximoDiaUtilPr($data, $saida = 'Y-m-d') {
// Converte $data em um UNIX TIMESTAMP
$timestamp = strtotime($data);
// Calcula qual o dia da semana de $data
// O resultado será um valor numérico:
// 1 -> Segunda ... 7 -> Domingo
$dia = date('N', $timestamp);

// Se for sábado (6) ou domingo (7), calcula a próxima segunda-feira
if ($dia == 6) {
    $timestamp = strtotime("+2 days",strtotime($data));
    $timestamp_final = $timestamp;
    //$timestamp_final = $timestamp + ((8 - $dia) * 3600 * 24);
}

elseif ($dia == 7) {
    $timestamp = strtotime("+1 days",strtotime($data));
    $timestamp_final = $timestamp;
    //$timestamp_final = $timestamp + ((8 - $dia) * 3600 * 24);
}

else {
    // Não é sábado nem domingo acrescenta um dia e incrementa prdia
    $timestamp = strtotime("+1 day",strtotime($data));
    $timestamp_final = $timestamp;
    $prdia++;
}
return date($saida, $timestamp_final);
//echo proximoDiaUtil('2016-09-04');
```

}

---

Apareceu o seguinte erro ao aplicar a solução que você propôs:

> Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
>   C:\Users#8188e\Desktop\sicob_atual\new_xampp\htdocs\geq\diautil.php
>   on line 41

Comment: E por que precisa disto? não parece ser necessário, mas pode ser só porque falta contexto.

Comment: Eu preciso que ele faça essa incrementação para contabilizar os dias úteis passados durante o acréscimo de data. 

Por exemplo tenho $prz = 30
e $prdia = 1;

Dessa forma toda vez que eu chamo a função de dias úteis e a data cai em final de semana eu realizo o acréscimo de $prdia mas quando cai em dia útil em faço um acréscimo à esta variável.

Comment: É que seu código não usa isto, então fica difícil enxergar essa necessidade. Sem vê-la me parece que não precisa, mesmo que diga que precisa.

Comment: Corrigindo meu comentário acima: 
...
Dessa forma toda vez que eu chamo a função de dias úteis e a data cai em final de semana eu NÃO realizo o acréscimo de $prdia mas quando cai em dia útil EU faço um acréscimo à esta variável.

Estou utilizando essa variável somente para que quando eu chamar a função e ela cair em dia útil a função me sinalizar isso trazendo a variável $prdia acrescida de um número, entende?

O que preciso é calcular um prazo ($prz) em dias úteis. Se houver uma forma mais fácil de fazer isso serve também.

Comment: Eu estou tentando entender a necessidade para poder ajudar, até porque isto é conceitualmente errado, mas tá difícil. Quando o requisito é confuso fica complicado achar a solução correta.

Comment: Entendi, amigo. vou tentar contextualizar melhor: O meu sistema obtém um determinado prazo que deve ser contabilizado em dias úteis. Eu obtenho esse prazo e a data base através de uma consulta ao banco de dados e armazeno cada um deles em uma variável. Após isso eu tenho que pegar essa data base e acrescentar 30 dias úteis a ela.

Answer (score 0):

Por que não usar um array como retorno?

```
function proximoDiaUtilPr($data, $saida = 'Y-m-d') {
// Converte $data em um UNIX TIMESTAMP
$timestamp = strtotime($data);
// Calcula qual o dia da semana de $data
// O resultado será um valor numérico:
// 1 -> Segunda ... 7 -> Domingo
$dia = date('N', $timestamp);

// Se for sábado (6) ou domingo (7), calcula a próxima segunda-feira
if ($dia == 6) {
    $timestamp = strtotime("+2 days",strtotime($data));
    $timestamp_final = $timestamp;
    //$timestamp_final = $timestamp + ((8 - $dia) * 3600 * 24);
}

elseif ($dia == 7) {
    $timestamp = strtotime("+1 days",strtotime($data));
    $timestamp_final = $timestamp;
    //$timestamp_final = $timestamp + ((8 - $dia) * 3600 * 24);
}

else {
    // Não é sábado nem domingo acrescenta um dia e incrementa prdia
    $timestamp = strtotime("+1 day",strtotime($data));
    $timestamp_final = $timestamp;
    $prdia++;
}
return array(date($saida, $timestamp_final), $prdia);
//echo proximoDiaUtil('2016-09-04');
}
```

Quando chamar a função, pegue o retorno dela e use as posições do array para recuperar a data e o $prdia

```
$foo = proximoDiaUtilPr();
echo $foo[0]; // exibe a data
echo $foo[1]; // exibe o valor de $prdia
```

Comment: Apareceu o seguinte erro ao aplicar a solução que você propôs:

Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\Users#8188e\Desktop\sicob_atual\new_xampp\htdocs\geq\diautil.php on line 4

Comment: editei a resposta para você entender melhor

Comment: Renato, eu tentei implementar a sua solução porém a função não me retornou  a variável $prdia com o acréscimo de 1. acrescentei na função:`code //acrescentei na função:
 return array(date($saida, $timestamp_final), $prdia);`
e no código: `code    $foo = proximoDiaUtilPr($data_corr_DU);
   $data_corr_DU = $foo[0];
   $prdia = $foo[1];
   echo $foo[0]."<br/>";
   echo $foo[1]."<br/>";`

Answer (score 0):

Galera, eu realmente estava pensando de forma incorreta pra resolver o meu problema bastava utilizar a função dessa forma:

Função:

```
function proximoDiaUtilPr($data, $saida = 'Y-m-d') {
// Converte $data em um UNIX TIMESTAMP
$timestamp = strtotime($data);
// Calcula qual o dia da semana de $data
// O resultado será um valor numérico:
// 1 -> Segunda ... 7 -> Domingo
$dia = date('N', $timestamp);

if ($dia == 5) {
$timestamp = strtotime("+3 days",strtotime($data));
$timestamp_final = $timestamp;
}
// Se for sábado (6) ou domingo (7), calcula a próxima segunda-feira
elseif ($dia == 6) {
    $timestamp = strtotime("+2 days",strtotime($data));
    $timestamp_final = $timestamp;
    //$timestamp_final = $timestamp + ((8 - $dia) * 3600 * 24);
}

else {
    // Não é sábado nem domingo, mantém a data de entrada
    $timestamp = strtotime("+1 day",strtotime($data));
    $timestamp_final = $timestamp;

}
return date($saida, $timestamp_final);
//echo proximoDiaUtil('2016-09-04');
```

}

Código principal:

```
if ($tipo_prz == 'DU'){
$prdia = 1;
  while ($prdia < $prz){
    $data_corr_DU = proximoDiaUtilPr($data_corr_DU);
    $prdia++;
 }
} 

$text = "".$prz.";".$tipo_prz.";".$data_corr_DU;   
fwrite($arquivoj, $text);
}
```